# Technology stack for a location based app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geolocation, sinatra, geospatial, postgis

This might sound like a trivial question to a lot of people, but since I'm just beginning my tryst with LBS, this is turning out to be a nightmare.

At the simplest, what I'm trying to do is build foursquare :) ..naa..it's a travel app with data for places, events, etc. Not a new / big thing really. What I'm confused about is how people are storing this location data. On one side I see postGis (which looks complicated) and on the other hand I see simpleGeo's hosted platform (which sounds perfect for quick development). Both store lat, long only (as far as I can understand). Is that really all to storing location data ? Of course, I'm not mentioning the ability for spatial queries - which are present both in simpleGeo and postGis.

Also, is it a good idea, to create a special service over REST (maybe using Sinatra) specifically for location data - different from the main web app ?

This question might sound incomplete or not even a question :) - cause I frankly don't have any clue how to go about a LBS.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What are your goals? Is it performance, features or scalability?

Comment: @gustav ...initially I just want to get it up and running with certain features..and then later look at performance and scalability. I could easily do it using a plain MySQL database (as far as I understand..the simplest is to store the lat, long of any place), but I want to make sure that when the time comes for complex location queries and data that I don't hit any bottleneck (perf and scalability both). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done a similar system using MongoDB as a spatial data server. The spatial queries that you will need to do for a system of this nature are quite simple, so no real need for a PostGIS store. MongoDB also has the advantage of being very quick to find and manipulate point data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get up and running fast. Start with MySQL. When you know your application and it's bottleneck you switch to a db fully or partly from what you have experienced.